# How do you create resizeable header images for iOS in Photoshop?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, photoshop, assets

I'm trying to create assets for a native iOS app. I know that I need to make my header images and buttons resizeable, so I'll need to create slices of the capped ends and a middle slice that stretches to full size.

My question is: how do I do this in Photoshop? Should I use the slice tool to make three separate slices and then export them as three .pngs? Or should I slice the ends and the middle, put it all together and export it as a single .png?

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Umm, what? Is this for a native app, or a mobile website that will be displayed on the iOS platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native iOS apps have an image API that supports resizing single images based on insets and a tiled inner area. See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), specifically `-resizableImageWithCapInsets:`. With that method, areas around the edges defined by the insets are not altered, while the remaining center region is tiled to fill any size.

You should aim to produce single images that can be used with that API in mind, while keeping tiled inner region as small as possible